# Define an array of Char as constant?

Tags: arrays, delphi, constants, delphi-10.3-rio

I use this function in Delphi 10.3.3:

```
function StrTrimCharsLeft(const S: string; const Chars: array of Char): string;
var
  I, L: SizeInt;
begin
  I := 1;
  L := Length(S);
  while (I <= L) and ArrayContainsChar(Chars, S[I]) do
    Inc(I);
  Result := Copy(S, I, L - I + 1);
end;
```

When I use the function in this way I get an error:

> [dcc32 Error]: E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'StrTrimCharsLeft' that can be called with these arguments

```
const
    BomChars = ['ï', '»', '¿'];
...
s := JclStrings.StrTrimCharsLeft(s, BomChars);
```

But when I use it in this way, all works well without an error:

```
s := JclStrings.StrTrimCharsLeft(s, ['ï', '»', '¿']);
```

So how can I define and use an array of `Char` as a constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write

```
const
  BomChars = ['ï', '»', '¿'];
```

you have declared a [*set*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Sets) named `BomChars` -- not an array!

If you instead declare `BomChars` as a [static array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Static_Arrays),

```
const
  BomChars: array[0..2] of Char = ('ï', '»', '¿');
```

it will work. (See [Declared Constants § Array Constants](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants#Array_Constants).)

(`StrTrimCharsLeft(s, ['ï', '»', '¿']);` works because here the brackets are part of the [open array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Open_Array_Parameters) syntax. Specifically, the brackets are part of an "open array constructor".)

Comment: So it is explicitly NOT possible to declare it as an OPEN ARRAY constant? How does this work in other languages?

Comment: @user1580348: There is no such thing as an "open array constant"; the concept doesn't even make sense. An [open array parameter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Open_Array_Parameters) is a special kind of *function/procedure parameter*, so they only exist in the context of function/procedure parameters. An open array parameter can accept static arrays, dynamic arrays, and this kind of construct. But in this case, a static array of three characters is exactly what you need, isn't it?

Comment: I mean, outside function parameters, Delphi only has two kinds of arrays: [static arrays](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Static_Arrays) and [dynamic arrays](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays). Basically, open array parameters allows you to define *a single* function that accepts both static and dynamic arrays as input. In particular, it will accept your static three-element array of characters.

Comment: In Delphi, square brackets are used for [sets](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Sets). Thus, your constant became a set. But the symbol is also used for the open array constructor, so the same symbol has two functions, which can be confusing. And since Delphi XE7, square brackets serve a third function (making it even more confusing): they can be used to create dynamic arrays on the fly: `var a: array of Integer; begin a := [2, 3, 1];`. But when it comes to declaring static array constants, you have always used the syntax with ordinary parentheses.

Comment: (Sorry, "open array parameters allows" should of course have been "open array parameters allow". But it is now too late to edit the comment.)